# how do i write in specific position in std out?

Tags: c++, cout

I write LZW/Huffman archiver with some of gzip keys. I need to implement an -l key which output info about archive. I'd like to write this info in the begining of the file. So i could use `seekp()` to write 8 bytes with size of completed archive in specific position. But it didn't work because i use `std::ostream*` pointer to operate on file (i need it to handle cases when working with std::in/std::out).

Is there any other way to do what i want? I don't really want to write everything in temp file before i write to std::cout.

Comment: Can't you construct the data in memory and then output it? Can you explain with some more detail for those that have no idea what the -l switch does? A short example of the output you're hoping for along with the data you have available in the program would help.

Comment: Seeking to write data at the beginning of a stream would write over the data already in stream. Not what you want for this. You would need to reserve space in the stream, then write the data, then seek back the the beginning and fill up the reserved space. This is hard to do with stdout because the data at the beginning of the stream has probably been squeezed out of the stream buffer and presented to the user. At that point you can't reliably take back.

Comment: How does using `std::ostream` prevent you from using `std::ostream::seekp`?

Comment: @RetiredNinja, how do i construct data in memory for 32gb archive?

Comment: I assume -l is some sort of text information listing, but since you did not describe what it is that is just a guess. Constructing text in memory is simple and common.

Comment: @RetiredNinja my -l key is equal to gzip -l key. it shows info about archive as a table `compressed / uncompressed / ratio / uncompressed_name`

Comment: Ok, so get those 4 numbers and print the whole line. Seems simple to me. You'll have to explain the specific trouble you're having, because what you describe wanting to do and a line with 4 values in it aren't really the same thing.  Seems like maybe an XY problem. Good luck.